# Native browser promise for a group of queried elements

Tags: javascript, promise

Is there a way to create a promise/fulfillment when querying elements/nodes? This doesn't work because I get `el` is `undefined` in the `var completed = elements.every(function(el) {  if (el.nodeType === 1)` iterator. In addition, because of the undefined the promise doesn't reject.

No jquery, please

```
var initialize = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  rippleElement = document.getElementById('ripple-element');
  toolbar = document.querySelector('#main-toolbar');
  headerName = document.getElementById('name-title');
  panel = document.querySelector('paper-header-panel[main]');
  drawer = document.querySelector('paper-drawer-panel');
  mainPanelContent = document.getElementById('mainPanelContent');

  //elements is not routing list, routing list is elementList
  var elements = [rippleElement, toolbar, headerName, panel,
      drawer, mainPanelContent];

  var completed = elements.every(function(el) {
    if (el.nodeType === 1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });

  if (completed) {
    resolve();
  } else {
    var errMsg = 'error in querying elements';
    reject(errMsg);
  }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you add if (el !== undefined && el.nodeType === 1) ? otherwise I don't understand your question.

Comment: As far as I can understand you want to wait for the elements to load before the promise is evaluated.... in that case wait for the dom ready event so that elements are loaded to the dom before the script is executed...

Comment: I was looking for a better way than handleing the `undefined`, but that works. I am using a polymer which isn't the normal dom ready.

Comment: `if(el){}` can test for existence.

Answer (score 1):

As @Arun said, perhaps you need to wait for the dom to be loaded if you don't use jQuery.

```js
var initialize = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

    function loaded(){
      
      var rippleElement = document.getElementById('ripple-element'),
          elements = [rippleElement],
          completed = _.every(elements, function(el) {
              if (el && el.nodeType === 1) return true;
              else return false;
          });
      
      
      if (completed) resolve();
      else reject('error in querying elements');
   
    }
  
    if (document.readystate === "complete"){
        window.addEventListener("load", loaded, false);
    } else {
        loaded();
    }

}).then(function(){
  // ok
}, function(err){
  // error
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
<div id="ripple-element"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```